# Pass json array to http flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to integrate this add stock feature into the app,but i am kind of stuck how do pass those incremented items data to http package,i have made view and shows data just like this

please checkout entire code for this process

https://github.com/Abhijithsp/flutter-image_upload/blob/master/Add%20Stocks.dart

Process

How do i pass the data just like this

```
{
    "id"        : "", //NOT NULL IF EDIT
    "station_id": 2,
    "name"      : "Test Stocks",
    "unit"      : "1", (DROPDOWN) ==>1 UNITS
    "branches"  : [{
        "branch_id": 87, 
        "kg"       : 10,
        "gm"       : 5,
        "ltr"      : 0,
        "ml"       : 0,
        "counter"  : 0
    },{
        "branch_id": 88, 
        "kg"       : 10,
        "gm"       : 8,
        "ltr"      : 0,
        "ml"       : 0,
        "counter"  : 0
    },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list_branch_details` along with its `StockBranchDetailsModel` store inside it for every rows. and whenever any change in data the you can save to particular position of that list named `list_branch_details`  and while sending data

```
var data ={};
var branches=[];
var branch ={};

data["name"] = "Test Stocks";
data["unit"] = "1";

for(int i =0;i< list_branch_details.length; i++ ) {
    branch = {};
    branch["branch_id"] = list_branch_details.get(i).getBranchId();
    branch["kg"] = list_branch_details.get(i).getKg();
    branches.add(branch);
}

data["branches"] = branches;
```

and just encode it.

```
jsonEncode(data);
```

Comment: it worked @Hardik Mehta